# Table in excel to one columns with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, multiple-columns, criteria

can you help me with function in excel. I tried function sumifs , but i think that exists something better.

I have this table,I need create columns VALUES in table below. Yellow values are fixed , but values in other color are variable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH

```
=IF(INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(G2,$B$1:$D$1,0))&""="","",INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(G2,$B$1:$D$1,0)))
```

[image]

If one has LET we can reduce the redundancy:

```
=LET(rslt,INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(G2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),IF(rslt&""="","",rslt))
```